# How to embed html with references (js, css) in .md file?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm an absolute beginner working with Jekyll sites and have currently the following issue:

I want to embed a calendar into my `index.md` (start page). The `index.md` only contains the yaml frontmatter so far. The calendar consists of a html-file referencing various `.js` (script src) and `.css` (link href) and all the files are located in a folder `"calendar"`.

I tried to embed the calendar with `{%include calendar.html}` and placed the file in the `_includes` folder. I also tried the `include_reference` but I haven't been successful with both options. The `.js` and `.css` files (referenced by the calendar.html) cannot be found. The path is wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Again: `index.md` with frontmatter is my starting page. The `calendar.html` is included in the `_includes` folder and the `calendar.html` references certain `.js` and `.css` which are located in a folder `"calendar"` (just below the main folder).
e.g.    is referenced and full calendar.min.js is located in the calendar folder.

Comment: Include seems right, so the problem should be the relative paths that calendar.html are using.

Comment: e.g. <script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>  is referenced and full calendar.min.js is located in the calendar folder.

Comment: Where is the calendar folder?

Comment: It' s in  /Users/N./website/

Comment: When I try to include a simple .html which references a jpg in the same folder, the error message is [2017-08-26 17:24:31] ERROR `/<test/16_surfer.jpg' not found. I don't know why there is a /<-Symbol (less symbol in the path). It is inserted automatically.

Comment: Please include all the relevant data in the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can only include an HTM fragment. If your `calendar.html` page is a complete HTML document with `html`, `head`, and `body` tags, then it won't work. Including that would result in invalid HTML.

Comment: can I do it vice versa and include the navigation.yaml into the html of my calendar? The html works fine, I just want to embed the navigation of my Jekyll site (and the footer).

Comment: are your problem still persist? read more the [jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/)